# When typechecking code from within a macro, is it possible to detect a typecheck failure caused by a macro expansion within that code?

Tags: scala, reflection, typechecking, scala-macros

I would like to write a macro that compiles code that it receives as a String literal and detect a typecheck error in the compiled code that is due to a macro expansion failure (either the macro was aborted, or the expanded macro failed to typecheck)

I was thinking something like this:

```
def myMacro(c: Context)(codeStringLiteral: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    val codeString = getString(codeStringLiteral) // this part is easy
    val ast = c.parse(code)
    val actualCode = util.Try(c.typecheck(ast)).recover{ case t: TypecheckException =>
      if(t.isMacroExpansionFailure) doOneThing
      else doOtherThing
    }
    c.Expr(actualCode.get)
}
```

Is this possible?

#### Context

Such a macro would make testing other macros much more pleasant by deferring to runtime a failure that is due to a macro expansion, thus allowing one to execute the entire test suite even when a test case for your macro is broken.

Of course, it is easy enough to simply differ typechecking entirely to runtime, but it would be really nifty to only differ errors that are due to the macro you are writing under test and fail at compile time if it's the test code itself that is at fault.

Of course, it's possible for an unrelated macro to fail, but it's unlikely to happen very often.

Comment: It's not what you're asking for, but you might look at Shapeless's `illTyped` for an example of the general approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an obscure flag for c.typecheck, called `withMacrosDisabled`. If you pass `true` there, that should prevent any macro from being expanded. Now you could compare the status of `c.typecheck(withMacrosDisabled = false)` and `c.typecheck(withMacrosDisabled = true)` and dispatch accordingly.

That won't work for whitebox macros, because `withMacrosDisabled = false` may make legit code using whitebox macros to fail typechecking, but for blackbox macros it should be more or less okay.

Comment: But my intention is to figure out whether the macro is at fault for the typecheck error. `c.typecheck(withMacrosDisabled = true)` only tells me whether there is a macro in the code or not (presumably there mostly is one, as it is the intention of this macro to help test other macros). Then `c.typecheck(withMacrosDisabled = false)` then only tells me where the whole thing typechecks or not. Am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed, withMacrosDisabled won't expand macros, but it's not going to fail typechecking if there are macros in the code. If a macro is blackbox, then you can typecheck it as a regular method, without expanding anything, and that's what withMacrosDisabled will do.

Comment: Oh, thx for clarifying! I incorrectly assumed it would behave otherwise. Yes, I believe this could work then.